# Laravel Eloquant Delete Child Table Row - onDelete('cascade') is not deleting child table row

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

Thank you in advance

I have 2 tables as below

```
1) users
2) reviews
```

The schema I have created is like below

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name',100)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
    });
   Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name',100)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

- When i am deleting the user, it is not deleting reviews belongs to the deleted user
- I am deleting user like below

  User::where('id',1)->delete();

  is there any short and simple and perfect way to do them for all the eloquent models?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code in your parent model :

```
public static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function ($model) {
      $model->relations()->delete();
    });
  }
```

*update for softDeletes

```
public static function boot()
{
  parent::boot();

  static::deleting(function ($model) {
  if($model->isForceDeleting()){
      $model->relations()->delete();//or forceDelete if child also using softDelete
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Alzafan Christian, Thank you for your help
I have checked with your code and seems not working
i have used laravel's soft deletes, so have to do something with that too?

Comment: yes, i will edit my answer
hard to type in reply comment sorry

Comment: Not working even with $model->relations()->forceDelete()
My parent and child both uses softdeletes

Comment: im using that code in the past, and it works perfectly.
if u want to force delete parent use Model::query()->ForceDelete();
can you check your database, as maybe it is already deleted, so in parent  you need to get softDeleted child with $model->relations()->withTrashed()